# Euclidean-geometry that came in board exams.How to solve this.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image]

I am sorry for the bad picture.Here PD is tangent and O is the center.Find the value of angle BAD.Is it possible?Then how?I don't know what to do?

Comment: No, you will need more information relating the cyclic quadrilateral and the triangle to find $\angle BAD$.

Comment: You can already deduce the value of angle $x$ due to the fact that DPO is a right triangle $x+2x+\pi/2=\pi$ ... But you can only do that. Not enough data. Check the hypotheses.